# How do I fix this load error during shell start?

Tags: ruby, shell, zshrc, asdf-vm

Whenever I start the shell I get an error from it saying that it could not load a gem, curiously named **ubygems** (notice the lack of **r**).

```
➜ reload                       
Traceback (most recent call last):
    1: from /home/ux/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.5.5/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
/home/ux/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.5.5/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require': cannot load such file -- ubygems (LoadError)

 * keychain 2.8.2 ~ http://www.funtoo.org
 * Found existing ssh-agent: 6895
 * Known ssh key: /home/ux/.ssh/id_rsa

Startup time: 623610 ms
```

Is this an issue with asdf or could it be something else?

Comment: `ubygems`? That sound like a typo. Very often you will have a line like `require 'rubygems'` in projects. Search for `ubygem` and in your app and replace it with `rubygems`

Comment: How do you start the shell?

Comment: @spickermann: not a typo. Was a little known feature of ruby. See my answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That feature ([`ubygems.rb`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_4_6/lib/ubygems.rb)) was removed in ruby 2.5: https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/2393

It was used to do a `require "rubygems"` from command-line, like this:

```
ruby -rubygems ...
```

Note that the "r" in `-rubygems` is a flag, meaning "require". And "ubygems" is the thing it requires. It was needed when rubygems weren't loaded by default. But now they are, so the feature doesn't make sense anymore.

You should change the command that opens the shell. Or switch to ruby before 2.5

Comment: You're right... Based on your comment and the ones above, I can now confirm this is actually coming from something I have on my `zshenv` which reads like

`export PATH="$PATH:$(ruby -rubygems -e 'puts Gem.user_dir')/bin"`

Running that bit on the shell results in the error I reported above. And only recently I began using Ruby > 2.5.

What is the correct way of accomplishing what the line tries to accomplish in Ruby > 2.5?

Comment: Found the answer on the linked Issue on Github. I need to have `ruby -rrubygems ...`  instead of a single r like I was doing

Comment: @PauloPhagula You can drop the flag altogether.